# InnoDB Plugin Version command?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is there any way to make MySQL tell you what version of the InnoDB plugin it's running? I know you can look at the documentation, but I'm trying to verify a potential bug if the plugin jives with the mysql version installed.

```
mysql> show variables like '%version%';
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| version                 | 5.1.50-community-log         |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | unknown-linux-gnu            |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, so I'll pass this along.

1.You must be running the InnoDB plugin instead of the built-in mysql innodb. To do this, you must make these config changes to your my.cnf:

```
ignore_builtin_innodb

plugin-load                     = innodb=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_trx=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_locks=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_lock_waits=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmp=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmp_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmpmem=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmpmem_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so

innodb_fast_shutdown            = 0
```

Note: Load individual plugins, but make sure no spaces between the ";". Also innodb_fast_shutdown is optional, but recommended.

2.You must restart mysqld to take the new config changes.

3.Using your SQL interface, execute: "SELECT @@innodb_version;"

```
mysql> SELECT @@innodb_version;
+------------------+
| @@innodb_version |
+------------------+
| 1.0.11           |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Reference URLs:

Getting the version:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_version

Using the plugin engine
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html

Comment: Be careful with generic advice on innodb_fast_shutdown.  Your setting here is to completely disable it (which can take quite a while).  The other options as 1 and 2.  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fast_shutdown

Comment: Yes, there is definitely a difference in behavior of the different shutdown levels. If you are considering running the InnoDB plugin, please read the manual.

Comment: I believe you should set the innodb_fast_shutdown to zero when converting from the builtin to the plugin InnoDB engine, so that all the changes in the logs are correctly flushed through. Then you should set it back.

Answer (score 0):

When you have installed InnoDB Plugin you can check out the version by performing the following commands

> - SELECT * FROM information_schema.plugins;
> - SELECT @@innodb_version;